# targetting only left and right divs, not middle

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

tried searching for this but haven't found a solution.

I would have a responsive wrapper with multiple (no set number) `div`'s.
So like a gallery!

I would like to only target the left and right `div`s and remove those(left `margin` for left div, right `margin` for the right div) `margin`s so that the `div`s are against the sides of the screen.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kggv4a0x/)

---

```css
.work {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 5%;
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper_work {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper_work'>
  <div class='work'>
    <p>
      this is my portfolio gallery
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='work'>
    <p>
      this is my portfolio gallery
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='work'>
    <p>
      this is my portfolio gallery
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='work'>
    <p>
      this is my portfolio gallery
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just to clarify after seeing your fiddle linked in answers comment, how many divs you want per row?

Comment: @dippas its responsive so it depends on the screen width (phone, computer, etc)

Comment: see my answer, might help you

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed it with a combination stuff

Comment: you're welcome, feel free to post your solution and/or mark one of above as accepted, eventually the one was more helpful to you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pseudo-elements first-child and last-child like this:

```
.work:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.work:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sswrL7pq/1/

Margins are probably not the way to go for a truly responsive layout with an arbitrary number of content divs, since you don't know which ones will be at the edges of your layout. There are some different ways of approaching it.

Flex box layouts:
You can style your container similar to this:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

The contents will be arranged in rows, with any extra space placed between the contents, leaving them flush with the edges. Flex box is for newer browsers, IE11+.

[Fiddle using flex layout](https://jsfiddle.net/sswrL7pq/5/)

For older browsers you can take advantage of inline-block and justify to get a similar effect. It isn't quite as clean but works quite well. The key styles are these:

```
.wrapper {
  font-size: 0.1rem;
  text-align: justify;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

[Fiddle using justify layout](https://jsfiddle.net/4gq45aLx/2/)

Comment: What happens when I have 4 divs?

Comment: The first and the last would be affected. The middle ones would remain the same.

Comment: Then the first and 4th would still be first and last.

Comment: Note css selectors were i ntroduced in css3 so the following support exists:  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/#browser-support

Comment: @DanWeber, it does not work in my `AnyAny` browser. Use you some shims?

Comment: lol @vp_arth, tables don't paste very well. Changed to a link.

Comment: @GandoeDyck, still works. Just wrong `technical specifications`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sswrL7pq/4/

Sorry for the confusion! This is what I meant to make. It has a wrapper and in that the divs are the "works".

Comment: Browser support points well made if you need to support older browsers. Worth noting that last-child was supported back to IE7. You can re-work it to use only right margins and last-child - which allows you to cut out first-child and support those older browsers.

Comment: Use something like bootstrap grid system

Comment: ahh I see what you're getting at. For that margins aren't really the way to go because in a responsive layout you never know which ones are at the end. You can use flex, or for older browsers clever use of justify to have the browser space divs for you.

Comment: @JamesWaddington would you be so kind to give a small example? I have not heard of this before! Old browser support is not important for this particular exercise. Help!

Comment: Sure. Here's a modified fiddle using the justify trick: https://jsfiddle.net/4gq45aLx/1/ and one using flex: https://jsfiddle.net/sswrL7pq/5/ note these are just quick fiddles, but show the general idea

Answer (score 1):

you can use **CSS 3 flexbox** for this:

**UPDATE**: Included images

```css
body,
p {
  margin: 0
}
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: black
}
p {
  min-width:20%; 
  margin:10px 0;
   border: red solid;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display:block;
  margin:auto
  
}
```

```html
<div class='work'>
  <p>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
  <p>
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
  <p>
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
  <p>
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
  <p>
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
  <p>
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/000">
  </p>
 
</div>
```

Comment: this is awesome! How can I target the top and bottom margins for the first and last row?

Comment: Hmm this does not seem to work with a width set? only min-wdith, and no max-width. this results in my images inside the div to grow large

Comment: @GandoeDyck sorry for delay, was having dinner, please take a look at updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.work:first-child,.work:last-child {
   margin: 5% 0;
}
```